# Exe file execution in Windows

Tags: windows, certificate

When I double click to execute an EXE file in windows7
the alert message pops up telling that the program does not have
certificate and could be dangerous.

But, if I compile some source code with my compiler(VC, C# whatever)
and execute the compiled binary, windows never asks me if the file
has certificate or not.

Why does this happens? I never signed my exefile.
how can windows tell that my compiled exe is secure but
other downloaded binaries are not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows somehow tracks origin of the files, you've downloaded from the internet. And on the first run it alerts you with the message.

As a solution, you can go to file properties (Right-click on the file and select `Properties`) and disable the checks:

[image]

Comment: thank you! I think windows leaves some kind of taint into file system meta data to distinguish their source